# How to persist NpgsqlCommand into a buffer

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I want to save changes to a local Postgres database to a remote database. I'm not using replication of any sort as the local system can't port forward and the local database represents one of many on the remote database, so log shipping is not an option either.

So I'm pushing changes made into a local Postgres database to a remote database by simply using the same NpgsqlCommand object, (that applies the change locally) changing the connection and executing it again.

I want to put that command into a buffer. Or in my case a table in the local database that acts as a queue. This is because the local system may have terrible connection issues and the software might close a lot, so persisting this queue of commands that must be sent of to another database is key for me.

The problem is, I can't put that command into a buffer, as a NpgsqlCommand object isn't serializable into a byte array which I was planning on saving in a bytea field. I also thought about breaking the command up into its components (statement and parameters) but the number of parameters and their types vary too much for me to consistently persist them, along with the prepared statement, into their own table.

How do I persist my NpgsqlCommand, in case my connection to the remote database fails, and my program closes? Was this the right train of thought to solve the problem?

The way I'm serializing my object for reference:

```
public static void AddCommandToRemotePushQueue(NpgsqlCommand commandToSave)
{
    try
    {
        NpgsqlConnection connection = GetNpgsqlConnection();

        //Open Postgres connection
        connection.Open();

        MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(memorystream , commandToSave);

        //Create NpgSQL command
        string commandString = $"INSERT INTO GlobalPushQueue (\"command\") VALUES(:command);";
        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(commandString , connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("command" , memorystream.ToArray()));

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: rather than trying to serialize the *command*, why not serialize the state that *leads to that command*; i.e. if the command relates to a specific action, you might serialize a SomeAction with properties related to the specific kind of action; then you just have a (presumably polymorphic) action queue to work with, and you build commands from actions as needed

Comment: *How do I persist my NpgsqlCommand* - create a class that embodies everything about the command in some props, and serialize that using some json serializer - or, even, have you tried running `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourNpgsqlCommandHere)` ? I'd be amazed if it doesn't catch enough to reconstitute a command later

Comment: @CaiusJard ADO.NET commands really aren't very serializer-friendly

Comment: Side note: **do not under any circumstances ever** use `BinaryFormatter`; it is very literally the worst possible choice - see https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/03/why-do-i-rag-on-binaryformatter.html (the main text is in the link in the last line - the rest is preamble)

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, but still, I'd expect the command text, and parameters collection to  be public properties and hence be picked up during a ser; while I don't know if a deser  to an NpgsqlCommand would produce a workable/executable command, it should be possible to build one from what is captured, whatever chosen route to deser it

Comment: ```BinaryFormatter``` bad, break the creation process of the command up into serializable chunks. Got it, thanks. Also this was my first post. What do I do from here? Do I have to pick an answer? Close the question?

Answer (score 1):

ADO.NET commands are inherently not designed for serialization.

Instead, consider storing the *state that lead to that command*; for example if the command relates to a specific action, you might serialize a SomeAction with properties related to the specific kind of action; then you just have a (presumably polymorphic) action queue to work with, and you build commands from each action in turn as needed. Persisting a queue of action objects that are your own simply types is simple with just about any serializer, although it is preferable if (as already mentioned) that serializer supports polymorphism - so you can have an `ActionBase` (and a queue of that), and then a `NewCustomerAction`, an `OrderEditedAction`, etc - each with the properties that define that action.

Also: for the serialization: *do not use `BinaryFormatter`. I cover the reasons for this in [this post](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/03/why-do-i-rag-on-binaryformatter.html) (and more importantly, the text linked from the last line), but the short version is "don't do that". Personally I'm partial towards protobuf-net (which would work just fine here), but I am admittedly biased.